# When iterating over a vector layer with pyqgis, how do I check whether a feature is selected?

Tags: pyqgis, select

While iterating over a vector layer using the following code (summerized from the example in the [pyqgis cookbook](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/vector.html#iterating-over-vector-layer)), is there a way to check whether a feature is selected?

```
provider = vlayer.dataProvider()
feat = QgsFeature()
allAttrs = provider.attributeIndexes()
provider.select(allAttrs)
while provider.nextFeature(feat):
    geom = feat.geometry()
    attrs = feat.attributeMap()
    for (k,attr) in attrs.iteritems():
        print "%d: %s" % (k, attr.toString())
```

Alternatively, I could create a list of selected features using `vlayer.selectedFeatures()`, but I'm hoping there is a way to check each feature directly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to directly find a feature object's parent layer or whether it's selected from a method in the QgsFeature class.

A similar approach to `vlayer.selectedFeatures()` is to test whether the `feat.id()` is in `vlayer.selectedFeaturesIds()`. QgsFeatureIds are not unique values compared with other vector layers, only within their own layer.

Alternatively, you could start with `vlayer.selectedFeatures()` and iterate over those features, instead of all features of the provider.

Yet another approach is to initially gather sets (or lists) of selected and non-selected feature ids for a given vector layer:

```
# previous relevant code

set_selids = set(vlayer.selectedFeaturesIds())
feat = QgsFeature()
vlayer.select([], QgsRectangle(), False)
set_allids = set()
while vlayer.nextFeature(feat):
    set_allids.add(feat.id())

set_notselids = set_allids - set_selids

print set_allids
print set_selids
print set_notselids
```

I can't seem to find a single call for retrieving a reference to all features (or ids) for a vector layer (i.e. still have to use `QgsVectorLayer.select()` and iterate with `QgsVectorLayer.nextFeature()`).

---

I updated the code to reflect QgsVectorLaer can handle select call (no need to get provider directly), and doesn't mess up actual selected features in map canvas, which would require `setSelectedFeatures()` to update.

After building feature id sets, you can iterate over them and use `QgsVectorLayer.featureAtId(featid)` to access the feature.