# Obtaining the data of one selected feature in QGIS using Python?

Tags: pyqgis

Is it possible to get the data of one selected feature in QGIS using Python, and if so how?

In my example I have a layer which shows some parcels for urban planning. If I now select one of the parcels I want to get the data for exactly this parcel. This data should be read out by an python script and then added to an automatically created PDF file. The last step is easy, but I didn't get the data from this selected feature.

It is possible to get data from the active layer, but is it also possible to get the data from one selected feature of this layer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Calling `layer.selectedFeatures()` will return a list with your selected feature(s).  You can then call `feature.attributeMap()` on each of the selected features to get a dictionary of each feature's attributes.

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
selected_features = layer.selectedFeatures()
for i in selected_features:
    attrs = i.attributeMap()
    for (k,attr) in attrs.iteritems():
    print "%d: %s" % (k, attr.toString())
```

I recently had a similar question answered here: [When iterating over a vector layer with pyqgis, how do I check whether a feature is selected?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/30935/4701)

Answer (score 10):

I just wanted to post some updates to the previous answer in light of [changes to the QGIS Python API since version 2.0](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/API_changes_for_version_20).

As before, you would get a list of selected features with `iface.activeLayer().selectedFeatures()`, however in `QGIS` versions `>= 2.0` you now use the function `QgsFeature.attributes()` instead of `QgsFeature.attributeMap()`. The two functions are not exactly the same: `attributes()` now returns a **list**, whereas the old `attributeMap()` returned a **dictionary**. Take a moment to browse the API documentation for [`QgsFeature.attributes()`](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsFeature.html#a8258e02e921454046b7aa6ff994fa8b4), [`QgsAttributes`](http://qgis.org/api/2.12/classQgsAttributes.html), etc to understand how attributes are stored/accessed.

If you're interested, you can read about some of the rationale behind the API changes on this mailing list thread: [[Qgis-developer] new vector api select features](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2013-February/024278.html). Briefly (in the words of QGIS developer Martin Dobias):

> Access to attributes: there is no `f.attributeMap()` anymore, because
>   attributes are now stored in a vector (Python: `list`) instead of a map
>   (Python: `dict`). `QgsFeature` class emulates python container object
>   [4](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2013-February/024278.html) so you can access attributes as if `QgsFeature` instance was a list
>   or dictionary, with keys being either field indices or field names:
>
> `f[0]`  ... first attribute
>
> `f["type"]`  ... attribute named "type"
>
> It is still possible to get all attributes: `f.attributes()` returns a list
>   of values.

So as an example of specifically what you asked how to do (get data for a single feature you've selected), suppose you had a layer of containing `city` features that each have a list of attributes, including a `county` attribute. To get the `county` value for a specific city you've selected (say `Helena, AR`), do the following in the Python console:

```
city = iface.activeLayer().selectedFeatures()[0]
city["county"]
# OUTPUTS: u'Phillips'
```

If you want the values of all of the fields in the city's attribute table, then you would just use:

```
cityData = city.attributes()
```

Comment: Also you can get the all of the field names from this example using 
 city.fields().names()  which would return a list of field names.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add something useful to the answer provided by J. Taylor and point that current accepted answer from 2012 is not correct anymore:

QgsFeature object supports useful `__geo_interface__` attribute, which returns a dictionary from a given feature. The dictionary is actually in a GeoJSON standard, so you get all attribute-value pairs and geometry included. The feature exists for some time now, first [described](https://gist.github.com/sgillies/2217756) by Sean Gillies sometime in 2012, with an [example usage here](https://nathanw.net/2013/06/25/adding-__geo_interface__-to-qgis-geometry-and-feature/). I couldn't find any information from which version of QGIS is it available from and I haven't tried QGIS 3 yet, but was surely available from at least QGIS 2.14.

TL;DR:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
selected_features = layer.selectedFeatures()
for i in selected_features:
    attrs = i.__geo_interface__
    print(attrs) # GeoJSON attributes of a feature
```