# Is it possible to take automatically a "screenshot" of my selected feature in QGIS using Python?

Tags: qgis, python

I am implementing a tool which allows the user to create a profile of a feature (in my case urban parcels). Is it possible to automatically take a screenshot of this feature (displayed in a QGIS window) and to display it in the PDF profile?

The picture should only show the extent of the feature and maybe a WMS-layer that lies beyond the feature. Are there already some tools which you could suggest?

Comment: How can I save a JPG instead of an PNG? QgsMapCanvas.saveAsImage (QString theFileName, QPixmap *QPixmap=0, QString="PNG") I know that I can use "JPG" as last parameter, but I dont know how to define the QPixmap that is excatly the same like the actual map window in qgis. Thanks for help. Micha

Answer (score 10, accepted):

kopi,

There are several approaches to a solution, but this may be one of the simplest (depending upon your needs):

**Select the feature using [QgsVectorLayer](http://doc.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#aa2e43a92fd5c2f4f9870c35cf37af409)**

Assuming a reference to your vector layer (vlayer) and the feature's id (fid). [See also](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30935)

```
vlayer.select(fid)
```

**Zoom to selected feature using [QgsInterface](http://doc.qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#a3eb15219832328689f22126182742c35)**

```
qgis.utils.iface.actionZoomToSelected().trigger()
```

**Deselect feature using [QgsVectorLayer](http://doc.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a0ff71c028c573834e144df06401a3ee6)**

```
vlayer.deselect(fid)
```

**Save canvas as picture using [QgsMapCanvas](http://doc.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html#a108893532699d6f52f04072a58a1d1c0)**

```
qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage('/Users/me/Desktop/feature.png')
```

This approach produces as large a photo as possible, if your window is expanded to full, because saving the canvas is at screen resolution. However, it does not ensure your pictures will be at the same map zoom scale, only relatively the same pixel size. There are other options like `QgisInterface::actionPanToSelected()` if you need to keep the zoom scale consistent.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for your answer! This works very good!

Comment: have a look also to the "easy print" plugin, probably not what you need, but it can be useful for inspiration.

Comment: Is it possible to set the scale before taking the screenshot? And how can I use "actionPanToSelected"? I am trying it this way: qgis.utils.iface.actionPanToSelected(feature which the function has to pan to...), but this returns an error message: "Attritbute Error: QgisInterface object has no attribute actionPanToSelected

Comment: Try [`qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().zoomScale(scale)`](http://doc.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html#a0ff77ba14d5443e13071f6766bbf25eb) to set map scale. [actionPanToSelected()](http://doc.qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#aaf1f94f6853c2ee145ff0332ce9ceb79) doesn't take a parameter, but returns a reference to the action itself (like actionZoomToSelected() above). Use its public slot `qgis.utils.iface.actionPanToSelected().trigger()` to fire the action, which will handle figuring out what is selected.

Comment: qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().zoomScale(scale) works. Thanks for that. The other one does not work for me. Its the same error as in my first post here in the comments.

Comment: Hmmm. qgis.utils.iface.actionPanToSelected().trigger() works for me under QGIS version 1.8.0. Are you using the latest stable version (1.8.0)? The feature was added [back in January](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/commit/42edad5ebcda03d270d90cd85706b0ec1e30f957), so it's [not in version 1.7.x](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/blob/release-1_7/src/gui/qgisinterface.h).

Comment: I was using 1.7.4.... Now it works (under 1.8.0), thanks!

Comment: @darkcarto, is there any way to make it automatically **zoom to selected features** using the python console ?,  want to combine this with **Time Manager** Plugin, so that my frame will move and zoom to selected features during x time interval.