# Embedding python to select feature in QGIS action

Tags: qgis, python, actions

I am working from QGIS actions with python and want go to select the current feature that I've identified using the identify tool.  (Key point is that there is a difference between identify and select).  What do I need for my action to make the current feature selected?

I have used
vlayer.setSelectedFeatures( [ ] ) 
but this so far hasn't allowed me to enter the current feature.

I've making use of previous posts to help me including:

[Is it possible to take automatically a "screenshot" of my selected feature in QGIS using Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31972/is-it-possible-to-take-automatically-a-screenshot-of-my-selected-feature-in-qg)

[How to create a QGIS action which copies features between layers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74263/how-to-create-a-qgis-action-which-copies-features-between-layers)

---

There is a little more to what I'm trying to achieve which is why I'm looking at actions.  Firstly I don't just want to select the feature I want to Zoom to the feature.  (I had sussed zooming to selected features).  The beauty of actions is that they are available from an attribute table and what's more in a relation within custom forms.  Hence I really wanted to achieve zooming to a feature using an action by right clicking on and attribute table.  These other options aren't available here.

An automated select on identify May be a solution, I would be interested learn more but would have to look at it.

The key is it needs to be a simple process for the user.

Comment: Did you know you can select features from the identify results window by right clicking on any of the feature's attributes and selecting "Toggle feature selection"?

Comment: I've come up with a solution that doesn't involve QGIS actions. After identifying a feature on the map using the Identify tool, the feature is automatically selected. Would you be interested in that?

Comment: @andrew-bell The solution I've talked about can also zoom in the selected feature. However, I'm getting lost with your question (requirements). If you cannot rephrase it in a way it denotes clearly what you want, I'm afraid I cannot help here.